# Upload file Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have jsp page:

```
    <form method="get" action="/save" type="multipart/form-data">
    File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br />
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

How can I upload file using spring mvc ? What Controller I must use?

I try write some this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  String uploadDo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                     @RequestParam ("name") String name) {

    return "success";
}
```

But how get data from file I don't know.

Hope you'll help me.

Comment: and now I get error: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current request is not a multipart request

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first thing:

Change the `RequestMethod.GET` to `RequestMethod.POST`. You are making a `POST` calling the `/save`.

Second: You have a `MultipartFile file` as a parameter and also in your `JSP` you have a `name=file`. So, inside your controller you can manage your `file` object. The `file` object is the actual file that is being uploaded.

Keep in mind that maybe you need to make some changes in Spring Security if you are using and maybe also in your Spring Configuration files.

Comment: Yes, I can change method to POST . But how can I get data from file object?

Comment: You can use for example `file.getName()`, or `file.getSize()`, etc.